# how to use data from two arrays in angular js to populate a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have two scope variables in my controller

```
$scope.data.items and $scope.bf_data
```

Now size of bf_data is always a multiple of data.items .

i am populating a table using this data like this

```html
<table>
          <tr>
            <th><div style="width: 100px" >Id</div></th>
            <th><div style="width: 250px" >Details</div></th>
            <th><div style="width: 150px" >Score</div></th>
            <th><div style="width: 70px" >HPSA Score</div></th>
            <th><div style="width: 55px" >BF Score</div></th>
     <th><div style="width: 50px" >BF Sum</div></th>
            <th><div style="width: 75px" >BQ Score</div></th>
     <th><div style="width: 50px" >BQ Sum</div></th>
            <th><div style="width: 70px" >Classifier Score</div></th>
            <th><div style="width: 70px" >Word Match</div></th>
     <th><div style="width: 70px" >Minreva Score</div></th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in data.items  " >
            <td><a href="{{ x.get }}">{{ x.id }}</td>
            <td>
                <p><b>{{ x.name[0] }}</b></p>
                <p><u>Brand</u>: {{ x.Brand }}; <u>Category URL</u>: {{ x.mlnURL }};<u>Price</u>: Rs {{x.Price}} </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p><a href="{{x.explain}}"><b>{{ x.score }}</b></a></p>
                Classifier Score: {{ x.cscore }} <br>
                Document Score: {{ x.sscore }} </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p><b> {{ x.hpsaScore_default }} </b></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p><b> {{ x.bf_value }} </b></p>
            </td>
     <td>
                <p><b> {{ x.bf_value_sum }} </b></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p><b> {{ x.bq_value }} </b></p>
            </td>
      <td>
                <p><b> {{ x.bq_value_sum }} </b></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p> <b> {{ x.cscore }} </b></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p> <b> {{ x.wordMatch }} </b></p>
            </td>
     <td>
                <p> <b> {{ x.minrevaScore }} </b></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Now in between this table i want to insert data from bf_data array . for the first row i want to print first $scope.data.items.length/$scope.bf_data.items.length elements from the bf_data array . In the new row the next $scope.data.items.length/$scope.bf_data.items.length items and so on ...

how can this be done .

I have modified the controller and now each item has a corresponding array with its value from bf_data . Now all i need to do is use another ng-repeat statement inside the previous one  but its not working .

the code looks like this

```html
 <table>
          <tr>
            <th><div style="width: 100px" >Id</div></th>
            <th><div style="width: 250px" >Details</div></th>
            <th><div style="width: 150px" >Score</div></th>
            <th><div style="width: 70px" >HPSA Score</div></th>
            <th><div style="width: 55px" >BF Score</div></th>
     <th><div style="width: 50px" >BF Sum</div></th>
            <th><div style="width: 75px" >BQ Score</div></th>
     <th><div style="width: 50px" >BQ Sum</div></th>
            <th><div style="width: 70px" >Classifier Score</div></th>
            <th><div style="width: 70px" >Word Match</div></th>
     <th><div style="width: 70px" >Minreva Score</div></th>
     <th><div style="width: 70px" >BF</div></th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in data.items  " >
            <td><a href="{{ x.get }}">{{ x.id }}</td>
            <td>
                <p><b>{{ x.name[0] }}</b></p>
                <p><u>Brand</u>: {{ x.Brand }}; <u>Category URL</u>: {{ x.mlnURL }};<u>Price</u>: Rs {{x.Price}} </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p><a href="{{x.explain}}"><b>{{ x.score }}</b></a></p>
                Classifier Score: {{ x.cscore }} <br>
                Document Score: {{ x.sscore }} </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p><b> {{ x.hpsaScore_default }} </b></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p><b> {{ x.bf_value }} </b></p>
            </td>
     <td>
                <p><b> {{ x.bf_value_sum }} </b></p>
            </td>
     
            <td>
                <p><b> {{ x.bq_value }} </b></p>
            </td>
      <td>
                <p><b> {{ x.bq_value_sum }} </b></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p> <b> {{ x.cscore }} </b></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p> <b> {{ x.wordMatch }} </b></p>
            </td>
     <td>
                <p> <b> {{ x.minrevaScore }} </b></p>
            </td>
     <td ng-repeat="y in x.bf_val " >
  <td>
                <p> <b> {{ y }} </b></p>
             </td>
     </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

The last part where i am appending the contents of array isn't giving the right output

Comment: if you know the index of array you  can directly use it

Comment: can you share rough mokup ?

Comment: @amoeba i have edited the question if it helps